# SQS Health check

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Since SQS is one of the AWS managed service, I do not have to worry about the availability.

But how about monitoring the health of the SQS? Any way we could gain some visibility over the SQS service to be a error free component? We have quite many lambdas connected to it and I want to monitor to ensure there is no error/latency/timeout etc..

Comment: You can only monitor the queues with CloudWatch AFAIK.

Comment: Slightly sarcastic: To monitor SQS, check Twitter to see if people complain that half the internet is down.

Answer (score 3):

From [What is AWS Health? - AWS Health](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/health/latest/ug/what-is-aws-health.html):

> AWS Health provides ongoing visibility into your resource performance and the availability of your AWS services and accounts. You can use AWS Health events to learn how service and resource changes might affect your applications running on AWS. AWS Health provides relevant and timely information to help you manage events in progress. AWS Health also helps you be aware of and to prepare for planned activities. The service delivers alerts and notifications triggered by changes in the health of AWS resources, so that you get near-instant event visibility and guidance to help accelerate troubleshooting.